# 'Variable' is declared but its value is never read VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently switched from Sublime to VScode - one thing that's been bothering me is that when functions and variables are not used, they are grayed out like a comment, with the message on hover,

> 'myVariable' is declared but its value is never read.

I can't find any setting to disable this syntax behavior in 'user settings', and I don't have an linter installed either. How do I change this?

Comment: Note that if you write to the variable, saying that it is 'unused' is a bug in eslint. See https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10710

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting :

```
"javascript.showUnused": false,
```

and

```
"typescript.showUnused": false,
```

if you are using those languages will eliminate the gray font and the hover message.

Additionally, for those using esLint you will get the squiggly under unused variables unless you put

```
"no-unused-vars": 0,
```

in  `.eslintrc.json` file in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

This not exactly a problem, after reading here I got to the conclusion this warning is actually usefull.
when it happen you know there is no reference to the variable declared on your code.

it ignore mentions made at other files pulling the script, so you got keep this in mind.